# Complex Sorting of a List

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of times from about 8:00am-7:00pm in string format. The am/pm is not specified, and using a 24 hour clock is not an option. I want to sort this list by time, but I'm running into issues after the clock strikes one, since numeric sorting begins at one, despite the fact that 8-12 are actually before that in terms of time. I was thinking I could create a new list of tuples where I ran the times through a function that converted them to a more appropriate number, sorted that, and used the first element of the tuple in the functions that needed that. This seems like it would work, but I fear I may be missing something a lot more elegant and fundamental. Am I?

Comment: Why not just store the numbers in a format that's more amenable to sorting, and then convert them on the fly? A natural choice would be `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter to `list.sort()` or the `sorted()` function to provide a value to sort on.

```
values.sort(key=somefunction)
```

where `somefunction` takes one argument (the value to be transformed).

The list will then be sorted based on the return value of the `key` parameter, but the original values are themselves left untouched.

For your problem, you can then use:

```
def daytime(val):
    hour, min = map(int, val.split(':'))
    if hour < 8:
        hour += 12
    return hour, min
```

which would transform `8:01` to `(8, 1)` and `6:25` to `(18, 25)`, causing `.sort()` or `sorted()` to sort `8:01` before `6:25`:

```
>>> sorted(['1:14', '8:01', '12:46', '6:25'], key=daytime)
['8:01', '12:46', '1:14', '6:25']
```

See the [Python Sorting HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/howto/sorting) for more details and tips (use this [Google cache link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3awiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/&hl=en&tbo=d&gl=no&strip=1) until `wiki.python.org` has recovered from the recent [security exploit](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-January/123499.html)).

Answer (score 4):

The function `to_minutes` converts a string to integer hours and minutes and calculates the number of minutes since 8:00 adding twelve hours to times before 8:00. Then it sorts according to this number of minutes:

```
def to_minutes(s):
    h,m = map(int, s.split(':'))
    return ((h - 8) % 12) * 60 + m

a = ['1:45', '8:00', '6:15', '12:30']
print sorted(a, key=to_minutes)
```

prints

```
['8:00', '12:30', '1:45', '6:15']
```